# Populate Handlebars template with JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars and Express. I want to display a list of tutors along with other tutor details based on a checkbox that the user selects. I am using an AJAX call to get the list of tutors from the server which is working fine, but I am unable to display the list.

Client side query:

```
function searchtutor(x) {
  $.get("/findtutor/find_tutor?search=" + JSON.stringify(x), function(
    data,
    status
  ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

This is the section I want to populate with JSON data:

```
{{# each tutors}}
{{# each this}}
<div id="tutorscolumn" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="card" style="width:225px">
    <img
      class="card-img-top"
      src="/images/{{ this.image }}"
      alt="Card image"
      style="width:100%"
    />
    <div class="card-body tutor-card-body">
      <h4 id="card-title" style="color: #134477;" class="card-title">
        {{ this.firstname }} {{ this.lastname }}
      </h4>
      <p id="card-text" style="color:#91959a;" class="card-text">
        {{ this.subjects }}
      </p>
      <button
        onclick="location.href='/users/view_tutor?email={{ this.email }}'"
        class="view_tut_btn button btn btn-lg"
        type="button"
      >
        View Tutor
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: you should include console.log(req) in question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you explain me more ?

Comment: Try to add more logs in your question so that people may help you. @HienNguyen asked you to use console.log(req) in your code and share the result that is shown in the console so that he can help you.

Comment: ok will do that soon

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your `console` output with some jQuery to display the compiled template output should do the trick:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(`
  ... template content here ...
`)

function searchtutor(x) {
  $.get("/findtutor/find_tutor?search=" + JSON.stringify(x), function(
    data,
    status
  ) {
    $('#tutors').html(template(data))
  });
}
```

The following snippet by way of demonstration, with faked data. I'm assuming you have a nested array in there because of:

```
{{# each tutors}}
{{# each this}}
```

The images will obviously be broken, but hopefully you get the idea!

```js
var template = Handlebars.compile(`
{{# each tutors}}
{{# each this}}
<div id="tutorscolumn" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  <div class="card" style="width:225px">
    <img
      class="card-img-top"
      src="/images/{{ this.image }}"
      alt="Card image"
      style="width:100%"
    />
    <div class="card-body tutor-card-body">
      <h4 id="card-title" style="color: #134477;" class="card-title">
        {{ this.firstname }} {{ this.lastname }}
      </h4>
      <p id="card-text" style="color:#91959a;" class="card-text">
        {{ this.subjects }}
      </p>
      <button
        onclick="location.href='/users/view_tutor?email={{ this.email }}'"
        class="view_tut_btn button btn btn-lg"
        type="button"
      >
        View Tutor
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
{{/each}}
`)

function searchtutor(x) {
  //  $.get("/findtutor/find_tutor?search=" + JSON.stringify(x), function(
  //  data,
  //  status
  //  ) {
  //    $('#tutors').html(template(data))
  // });
  $('#tutors').html(template(dummyTutors))
}

var dummyTutors = {
  tutors: [
    [{
      id: 1,
      image: '',
      firstname: 'Gertrude',
      lastname: 'McWombat',
      email: 'gertrude@example.com',
      subjects: 'Wombats'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      image: '',
      firstname: 'Gershwin',
      lastname: 'Aardvarkson',
      email: 'gershwin@example.com',
      subjects: 'Aardvarks'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      image: '',
      firstname: 'Gerald',
      lastname: 'Xebublip',
      email: 'gerald@example.com',
      subjects: 'Xebus'
    }]
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.4.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="searchtutor('ger')" name="search">
<label for="search">Search</label>
<div id="tutors"></div>
```